# Reduce margins of a PDF with \includepdf

Tags: margins, pdfpages

I have a *book* in pdf and I need to reduce all the margins. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={21-40},nup=1x1,
 offset= 0 0, 
 delta= 0 0,
 fitpaper=true,
 noautoscale=false]{book.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Any help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can use `trim=Left Bottom Right Top, clip`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={21-40},fitpaper=true,
            trim=35mm 10mm 15mm 15mm, clip]{book.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the following code to import a PDF file and scale it as you want:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\includepdf[pages=-,noautoscale = true,scale=.8]{<Your-file>}
```

Comment: Are you sure that will reduce the margins as requested? I do not think so, your solution let the margins unchanged, but scaled down ... BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=17cm,page=1]{Book.pdf} %You modify 17cm to set it as you want and the page number like 1-7 or type 0 to have it all.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\includegraphics` can only include *one* image, not a series of pages. Also this *adds* a new margin from the current document in addition to the margins of `Book.pdf`.