# How to allow page break with pdfpages package?

Tags: page-breaking, pdfpages, split

I am trying to find a way how to allow my included pdf document to split between two pages. Currently, I am adding a pdf document as an appendix. Since the pdf's first page is too big it does not fit in the current chapter start page but on the next one. See the image bellow:
[image]

The code I use is: `\chapter{Ethics Form}
\includepdf[pages=-,scale=.8,pagecommand={}]{ethics-form.pdf}`

Any ideas how I can force the page to split between pages? Thank you in advance

Comment: you would have to do this by hand, include it once clipping to the top of the included page then include the same page again, clipping to the bottom. But I wouldn't do this I'd just think of some text to write under the heading and then include the page as a page as shown.

Comment: or just drop the "Ethics Form" heading, which isn't really needed and just scale it to fit under the Appendix N heading

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325271/reduce-margins-of-a-pdf-with-includepdf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your suggestions! I did try to clip the sides of the included pdf but did not work (e.g. move the mage to the chapter titile page). Also, I still want this appendix to be titled "Appendix N" since without it latex includes it in the previous appendix M

Comment: There is always the "THIS PAGE INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK" approach.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This is actually a very good point. I may go with this approach