# Remove the page numbers of included PDF file in Latex

Tags: pdfpages

I write a report in LaTeX for my study. In my report I have to include a PDF file. If I include the PDF file than I see the page number of the PDF file and the page number of my LaTeX PDF file. I want to remove the page number of the included PDF file but I don't know how. I use the following command:

`\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\chapter{Anhang}\pagestyle{plain}}]{Downloads/Interaktion_durch_Widgets/Interaktion_durch_Widgets-V2.pdf}`

What do I have to change to get rid of the page numbers from included PDF file?

I have read the sites that you have sent me in the comments and I changed my command with use `trim` and `clip`. So my idea was to cut off the page number and use the command `\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\chapter{Anhang}}, trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 5cm, clip]{Interaktion_durch_Widgets-V2.pdf}`

But the page number of the PDF file is still visible which u can see in the follow image

[image]

Comment: The "inner" page numbers are an integral part of the PDF included as graphics. Treat it as regular graphics, hence you must either overlay or crop the unwanted contents.

Comment: Also related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25806/how-can-i-crop-included-pdf-documents, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325271/reduce-margins-of-a-pdf-with-includepdf, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443540/trimming-the-blank-space-in-pdf-image-for-insertion-in-tex-file

Comment: I used the command ```trim 0cm 0cm 0cm 10cm, clip``` and i still see the page number of my PDF file

Comment: @Reazelruss We don't know how your included PDF looks and the positioning of "inner" page numbers. How do you expect us to trim and clip correctly?

Comment: @Reazelruss The forth parameter of `trim` means the top,  the second the bottom. And your are missing an equal-sign after `trim`: Try this `[trim=0mm 80mm 0mm 0mm, clip]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the footer (say) of the page you're including because it has the page number in it from the original document you have 2 options. Let's assume you have the following setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

% ...include PDF here

\end{document}
```

When you just include the PDF on the following page, this is what it looks like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\includepdf[
  pages=1,
  pagecommand={}
]{lipsum50}% lipsum50.pdf is a document with \lipsum[1-50] in it

\end{document}
```

Here's a close-up of the page numbers on the second page:

[image]

The two options to remove the page number (1 in this case) include

1. Use the `trim` and `clip` options provided by [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) for `trim`ming and `clip`ping included graphics. From the [`pdfpages`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/pdfpages):

> Internally the command `\includepdf` makes use of the
> `\includegraphics` command from the `graphicx` (actually `graphics`)
> package. Hence it is possible to use all the options of
> `\includegraphics`, too. Options which are not interpreted by
> `\includepdf` are passed directly to `\includegraphics`.
>
> Especially
> the `trim` and `clip` options of `\includegraphics` are quite useful,
> if only parts of a page should be inserted. (Maybe to cut off the
> header and footer of the inserted pages.) Just use the `trim` and
> `clip` options as if they were options of `\includepdf`. They will be
> passed to `\includegraphics` internally.

And here is how the `trim` option should be used (from the [`graphicx` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/graphicx)):

> **`trim`**
>
> Similar to `viewport`, but here the four lengths specify the amount to
> remove or add to each side. `trim= 1 2 3 4` "crops" the picture by `1`bp at
> the left, `2`bp at the bottom, `3`bp on the right and `4`bp at the top.

Note that `bp` here refers to `b`ig `p`oints, but you can specify other unit lengths. The the sake of brevity, let's trim 2cm off the top and bottom of the included page so it will remain vertically centred:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\includepdf[
  pages=1, 
  pagecommand={},
  trim=0 2cm 0 2cm,
  clip
]{lipsum50}

\end{document}
```

2. Overwrite the page number with a white box so it's not visible.

Using the same example as above, we use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) with some trial-and-error positioning of the white block in the `F`ore`G`round.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages,eso-pic,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{% Place content in the ForeGround of the current page only
  \AtPageLowerLeft{% Start placement at the lower-left of the page
    \makebox[\paperwidth]{% Move to the middle (horizontally) of the page
      \raisebox{3.5em}{% Raise box 5em from the bottom of the page
        \colorbox{orange}{% Use white instead; orange just for illustrative purpose
          \rule{2em}{0pt}% width
          \rule{0pt}{2em}% height
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\includepdf[
  pages=1, 
  pagecommand={}
]{lipsum50}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay it works. How can I use it when I have more than one page ?

Comment: @Reazelruss: If you go with the first option, there's no issue with including multiple pages since the `trim` and `clip` options would be the same for all pages. Are you using this option, or the second?

Comment: I only tried the second method because the first one didn't work for me. Now I tried the first method with your command ```trim=0 2cm 0 2cm, clip``` and it worked. The page number is gone. So I can use this method for an included PDF file that has many pages. Thank you for your help and your detailed answer.

Comment: @Reazelruss: If my answer solved your problem, consider accepting it. See [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)